# pyodbc - get results of alter statement

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc

I am trying to get the result of an 'alter' statement I am running through pyodbc.

My code:

```
...
connection = pyodbc.connect(connection_string, autocommit=True)
cursor = connection.cursor()
query = "ALTER INDEX index_name ON schema.table REBUILD"
cursor.execute(query)
...
```

Since this is not a query, I cannot use `curosr.fetchall()`. How can I find the result of my statement?

Some indexes will fail because the user running the script doesn't have permissions (or because of some other reason), and I would like to display the error message thrown by the server (there is no exception raised by the cursor).

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your issue. When I try and run that command as a user without sufficient privileges (i.e., not `db_ddladmin`) I get "pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Cannot find the object "dbo.MillionRows" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions. (1088) (SQLExecDirectW)')".

Answer (score 1):

You could execute the statement(s) dynamically (exec or sp_executesql) in a try/catch block which returns a message for success&error:

```
--exec
begin try
    exec('
    --statement goes here
    ALTER INDEX index_name ON schema.table REBUILD
    ');
    select cast(N'success' as nvarchar(2048)) as errormsg, 0 as errornumber;
end try
begin catch
    select error_message() as errormsg, error_number() as errornumber;
    --..maybe some transaction handling...for statements with transactions..
    --if @@trancount > 0
    --begin
    --   rollback transaction
    --end
end catch

--sp_executesql
declare @sql nvarchar(max) = 'ALTER INDEX index_name ON schema.table REBUILD';
begin try
    exec sp_executesql @stmt = @sql;
    
    select cast(N'success' as nvarchar(2048)) as errormsg, 0 as errornumber;
end try
begin catch
    select error_message() as errormsg, error_number() as errornumber;
end catch
```

Try/catch is not completely graceful, some errors abort the connection (depending on the severity of the error) and there should be some kind of exception handling at the caller:

```
begin try
    exec ('
    --statement goes here
    raiserror(''xxx'', 20, 1) with log
    ');
    select cast(N'success' as nvarchar(2048)) as errormsg, 0 as errornumber;
end try
begin catch
    select error_message() as errormsg, error_number() as errornumber;
end catch
go

--transaction handling
begin try
    exec ('
    --statement goes here
    begin transaction
        declare @a int;
        select @a = ''A'' --aborts the batch
    commit transaction  --<-- this is not executed
    ');
    select cast(N'success' as nvarchar(2048)) as errormsg, 0 as errornumber;
end try
begin catch
    select error_message() as errormsg, error_number() as errornumber;
end catch
--error here: Uncommittable transaction....
go
begin try
    exec ('
    --statement goes here
    begin transaction
        declare @a int;
        select @a = ''A'' --aborts the batch
    commit transaction  
    ');
    select cast(N'success' as nvarchar(2048)) as errormsg, 0 as errornumber;
end try
begin catch
    select error_message() as errormsg, error_number() as errornumber;
    if @@trancount > 0
    begin
        rollback transaction;
    end
end catch
```